# Put an icon in the Toolbar

Tags: android

I have a toolbar that has only the menu icon, and it is setted programmatically, like this:

```
    myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now, i would like to have another icon in the toolbar, and associate to it my src image and onClick Method. As you can see I don't have a xml menu file, and i also don't want to set a default android icon, so how can I perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of Toolbar is using custom layout!
You can add whatever UI elements, like button, to your Toolbar and find them in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a CustomView to the ActionBar by supplying a layout file or View object. In that custom view you can do whatever you want.

Here is how you can set custom view to the action bar

```
 protected void setCustomActionBarTitle(String title) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_action_bar_title);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
            titleView.setText(title);
            ImageView customIconImageView = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.custom_icon);
            customIconImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // call my method on the activity
                }
            });
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.up_icon);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use a separate xml file to [setup your](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) menu and [define any extra buttons (item)](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html) in there. Here is sample menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/action_favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the icon which you want in your menu --> menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_scan"
    android:icon="@drawable/camera_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_scan"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

and in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /* Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me,

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add your icons into your tool bar. Override these methods and use the code in your project..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dashboard, menu);
    menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_about));
    menu.getItem(1).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.street_view_icon));


    return true;
}



//Notification Icon

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title

    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {


       case R.id.action_notify_found:
       Intent aboutIntent=new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, HomeAboutActivity.class);
       startActivity(aboutIntent);


        case R.id.action_notify_found1:

       Intent ARStreetviewintent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, ARStreetviewActivity.class);
       startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, StreetviewActivity.class));

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">




<!-- Notification Found -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_notify_found"
    android:icon="@drawable/about"
    android:title="About"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<!-- Notification Found -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_notify_found1"
    android:icon="@drawable/street_view_icon"
    android:title="StreetView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```